# Microsoft Azure AD Graph API to add member to a group

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to add members to a group using `Microsoft graph API`, was able to add member to the group to which Application owner is the owner of but not to the group that was created by other member.

When I try to add member to the group and Application owner is not the owner of the group, I am receiving the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2c5a99ff-70XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "date": "2X-XX-XXXX 23:42:54"
        }
    }
}
```

[These are the permissions given to the App API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwpGt.png)

Can someone help me understand how the add member to group works with `Azure`? only group owner will be able to add member to the group? Is there any configuration that needs to be enabled for Application to let Application owner add member to any group?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Delegated permissions, the effective permissions of a token will be the combined permissions of the app and user.
If the user does not have the necessary role/ownership, then your app can't do it either.

If your app needs to act with more permissions than the user has, you'll need to use application permissions instead of delegated permissions. 
To use app permissions, your app back-end must acquire tokens using the client credentials flow, which does not involve a user. 
In this case only the application's app permissions matter, delegated permissions will have no effect.

Comment: I have added both delegated and application permissions to this application. Application API permissions include the following
Directory.ReadWrite.All
Group.ReadWrite.All
GroupMember.ReadWrite.All

Are there any other permissions that needs to be provided at app level?

Comment: GroupMember.ReadWrite.All alone should be enough, as defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http